# c# - how to get child element val where another child element equals to a val

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get a child element's value where another child element value equals to a value,

for example I have this xml file:

```
<CATALOG>
    <game>
        <name>Assassins Creed Origins</name>
        <picture>pic1</picture>
        <torrent>file1</torrent>
    </game>
    <game>
        <name>mylifeisdone</name>
        <picture>pic2</picture>
        <torrent>file2</torrent>
    </game>
</CATALOG>
```

I want to get `picture` value where `name` equals to `mylifeisdone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I could think of is using `XDocument`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<CATALOG>
<game>
<name>Assassins Creed Origins</name>
<picture>pic1</picture>
<torrent>file1</torrent>
</game>
<game>
<name>mylifeisdone</name>
<picture>pic2</picture>
<torrent>file2</torrent>
</game>
</CATALOG>");

var picture = doc.Descendants("game")
    .First(g => g.Element("name").Value == "mylifeisdone")
    .Element("picture").Value;
```

This first gets all elements "game" and searches for the first element, of which the `name` element has the value "mylifeisdone"; after that, it retrieves the value of the "picture" element.

Note: you may need the namespace `System.Xml.Linq` and, if you are reading the XML from a file, use `XDocument.Load("path")`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> games = doc.Descendants("game").ToList();

            string picture = games.Where(x => (string)x.Element("name") == "mylifeisdone").Select(x => (string)x.Element("picture")).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.